Implementing a custom routing function in AnyLogic instead of findShortestPath
I hope you are having a good day. I recently tried to develop a custom routing function in AnyLogic and found that findShortestPath() function is used for routing by default.
Is there any way to implement my own function and use it instead of findShortestPath()? If you have any idea and share it, it would be extremely helpful for developing my model.
Thank you for reading this question.
